# Grouped buttons in Iphone

Tags: iphone, uibutton

I have a problem. I have a View1Controller with 16 buttons, the name of this buttons are button1, button2, button3...button16.

I can select and deselect this button, and when i do it, you touch other button to change View2Controller.

In View2Controller, i want show the name of the buttons by group that was selected in View1Controller. For example, if i selected in View1Controller button1, button2, button3, button4, button8, button11, button12, button13.  I want that in View2Controller show:

SELECTED:

1. From button1 to button4
2. button8
3. From button11 to button13

How can i gruped it?

Thanks friends.

Best regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be many ways to do it. What comes to mind now is to have an array for each group. When user taps add an entry in appropriate group(array). 
Pass the array to next view controller.

EDIT : Assign sequential tags to your buttons. Add the tag to array in the button action. Process the array.

Comment: I need to know which buttons are selected in sequential order to group them and what not. My problem is not how I can move the buttons to select another view ...

Comment: Thats your wish. Its answered your question.